# How to keep <li> visible after click?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs3, tailwind-css, inertiajs

I am trying to create a component for a sidebar. The behavior I want is very simple, when clicking on "users" another child link (list) is displayed.

[image]

The problem is that when the "list" link is clicked, it is hidden again.

[image]

It seems that when clicking, the component goes back to the previous state.

I was not able to discover my mistake. Any tips?

Laravel 8 + Inertiajs + Tailwindcss + Vue3

My code is:

HTML

```
<template>
    <aside class="menu bg-green-500 text-white border-r border-gray-400">
        <div class="flex justify-center items-center h-14 bg-gray-800">
            Brand
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col">
            <ul>
                <inertia-link href="/">
                    <li class="flex items-center p-5 hover:bg-gray-700 cursor-pointer"
                    :class="isUrl('') ? 'bg-gray-700' : ''"
                    >
                        <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt mr-2"></i>Dashboard
                    </li>
                </inertia-link>
                <li class="flex flex-col p-5 hover:bg-gray-700 cursor-pointer" :class="isUrl('users/index') ?
                    'bg-gray-700' : ''">
                    <!--  -->
                    <a href="#" class="flex items-center" @click="usersMenu = !usersMenu">
                        <div class="flex-grow">
                            <i class="fas fa-users mr-2"></i>Users
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <i class="fas" :class="{'fa-angle-down': usersMenu, 'fa-angle-left': !usersMenu }">
                            </i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="flex flex-col pt-5" :class="{ hidden: usersMenu }">
                        <inertia-link href="/users/index">
                            <li class="flex items-center h-14 px-6 hover:bg-gray-600 cursor-pointer rounded"
                                :class=" isUrl('users/index') ? 'bg-gray-600' : ''" >
                                    <i class="fas fa-list mr-2"></i>List
                            </li>
                        </inertia-link>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </aside>
</template>
```

JS

```
<script>
export default {
    name: "Menu",
    data() {
        return {
            usersMenu: true
        };
    },
    methods: {
        isUrl(...urls) {
            let currentUrl = this.$page.url.substr(1);
            if (urls[0] === "") {
                return currentUrl === "";
            }
            return urls.filter((url) => currentUrl.startsWith(url)).length;
        }
    },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Reviewing the [Inertiajs documentation](https://inertiajs.com/pages), I found information about persistent layouts, so I modified my content pages to import the persistent layouts.

Example: I changed my dashboard page to:

```
<script>
import Llayout from "../Shared/Llayout.vue";
export default {
    name: "Dashboard",
    //   components: {
    //     Llayout,
    //   },
    layout: Llayout,
};
</script>
```